# Summing products of entries of a matrix in an efficient way

Tags: r, performance, matrix, sum

Suppose that `A` is a `n x n` symmetric matrix with real entries. I want to calculate the sum of `A[u,t]*A[t,s]*A[s,u]` when `s,t,u` goes from `1` to `n`. A simple way to do this is as follows.

```
n<-5
A<-matrix(sample(1:n^2),n)
A<-A%*%t(A)
isSymmetric(A)
S1<-0
for (s in 1:n)
    {
        for (t in 1:n)
            {
                for (u in 1:n)
                    {
                        S1<-S1+A[u,t]*A[t,s]*A[s,u]
                    }
            }
     }
print(S1)
```

However, this is slow and inefficient. I came up with the following more efficient code.

```
S2<-0
for (s in 1:n)
    {
        S2<-S2+sum(t(A*A[,s])*A[,s])
    }
print(S2)
S1==S2
```

Is it possible to improve this code even further so that we do not have to use the loop altogether?

Comment: Try `sum(apply(A, 2, function(x) { sum(t(A*x)*x)) })`

Comment: Maybe you could use some matrix multiplication instead of loops.

Comment: Someone posted a nice answer to my question. Later on the answer was deleted and I cannot see it anymore. Could someone undelete that answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
sum(A * A %*% t(A))
```

Relating F.Prives comments, lets test different approaches:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 10
A <- matrix(sample(1:n^2), n)
A <- A %*% t(A)
require(Matrix)
X <- forceSymmetric(A)

m1 <- sum(A * A %*% t(A))
m3 <- sum(X * X %*% t(X))

all.equal(m1, m3)
# [1] TRUE


bench::mark(sum(A * A %*% t(A)),
            sum(X * X %*% t(X)), check = F, relative = T)[, 1:10]
# # A tibble: 4 x 10
# expression                     min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time
# <chr>                     <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm>
# 1 sum(A * A %*% t(A))           12us  17.26us  13.26us    334us    57929.    1.66KB     1  9999      173ms
# 3 sum(X * X %*% t(X))            1ms   1.43ms   1.16ms     41ms      701.    5.28KB     1   278      397ms
```

It looks like that for small matrices base matrix is faster.

For `n <- 1000`:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 10
# expression                     min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time
# <chr>                     <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm>
# 1 sum(A * A %*% t(A))          659ms    695ms    694ms    731ms      1.44    15.3MB     0     5      3.47s
# 3 sum(X * X %*% t(X))          708ms    749ms    759ms    774ms      1.34    45.8MB     0     5      3.74s
```

Also the base is a little bit faster.

p.s.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  expression                     min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time
  <chr>                     <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm>
1 sum(A * A %*% t(A))          673ms    769ms    714ms    894ms      1.30    15.3MB     0     5      3.84s
3 sum(X * X %*% t(X))          710ms    721ms    716ms    745ms      1.39    45.8MB     0     5       3.6s
5 sum(tcrossprod(A) * A)       399ms    407ms    403ms    418ms      2.46    15.3MB     0     5      2.03s
6 sum(tcrossprod(X) * X)       402ms    423ms    424ms    436ms      2.37    30.6MB     0     5      2.11s
```

`sum(tcrossprod(A) * A)` will be faster and gives the same result

Comment: Don't forget to use `tcrossprod` instead of `%*% t()`. You can also use a special data format for symmetric matrices (thanks to package {Matrix}).